# XMLDSig standard signature, must also comply with XAdES-BES standard in C#

Tags: c#

My dear Sirs, I need to sign an xml to comply with the XMLDSig standard, it must also comply with the XAdES-BES standard. in C#, in this format:

```
<ds:Signature 
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e7896cd0">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"> 
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"> 
</ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e70-48b152896cd0-ref0" 
URI="#CV3220627253095794000010100000000209051986238">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"> 
</ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>qQPFv+nWie8pbwUlgBWD2H9hzZtK/E=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-809d73-411f-8e70-48b152896cd0-keyinfo">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>O6vdUpwOQh9H5BFTwrdOEnSkFi0653Gvh4=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73- 
70-48b152896cd0-signedprops">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>13x9mrEZtldUEgHofrznSCKTrL1RPQtJxeD/Idgb9Nc=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e70-48b152896cd0-sigvalue">
IP2H4P8VqoMyer5TlFOg7ElkVA=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e70- 
48b152896cd0-keyinfo">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIQyDy3ReOT5Usgx/lS7szPaf7J1mptx7J7nMNFW&#xD;DG26JjBKF+xbHM4=
</ds:X509Certificate>
<ds:X509IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>cn=TesteSispCA</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>691455013706561</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</ds:X509IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509SubjectName>c=CV,o=A Economia E Gestao ,2.5.4.97=CV-2530994,ou=Fatura 
Eletronica,cn=AB,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=miaegestao</ds:X509SubjectName>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e70- 
48b152896cd0"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e70-48b152896cd0- 
signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2022-06-27T14:41:01.782- 
01:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest> 
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod> 
<ds:DigestValue>6/OH7zBR7dT/W6fwYi/WR58ld3jabGYQOKSPpwOuxF0=</ds:DigestValue> 
</xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>cn=TesteSispCA</ds:X509IssuerName> 
<ds:X509SerialNumber>6914550136706561</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert> 
</xades:SigningCertificate></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties> 
<xades:UnsignedProperties><xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties><xades:SignatureTimeStamp> 
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"> 
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod> 
<xades:EncapsulatedTimeStaJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIVVjCCFVICAQMxDzANBglghkgBZQMEAg
Kl6iR0xeKdnc</xades:EncapsulatedTimeStamp></xades:SignatureTimeStamp> 
</xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties></xades:UnsignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties> 
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

I signed one but it just gives the error Unable to verify signature. Reference '#CV3220624253095794000010100000002707385730942' cannot be validated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that you provide to the validator a *ds:Signature* alone, without the referencing signed data.

I.e. you have the reference with *Id="xmldsig-8096cc3f-7d73-411f-8e70-48b152896cd0-ref0"*, referencing an XML node by its URI attribute : *URI="#CV3220627253095794000010100000000209051986238"*.

As defined within [XMLDSig](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-ReferenceProcessingModel) "4.4.3.2 The Reference Processing Model", a reference starting from '#' character refers a node within the current XML document, containing the signature.

Therefore, you shall provide the originally signed content with *Id="CV3220627253095794000010100000000209051986238"* within the same document as the signature to the validator, without extracting the signature element.

Then the validator shall be able to correctly de-reference the signed content.

In case you do not want to share the signed content together with the signature, you may consider a detached signature format. In a detached format the signature is present within a separate file than the original signed document.